# How to install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel on RHEL Server 6.3?

Tags: redhat, java, yum, rhel6

I have need of installing a Java 7 development environment on a RHEL 6.3 (system details are below).  Following the [official OpenJDK directions](http://openjdk.java.net/install/) I tried `yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel` (as root).  This yields the error message:

```
No package java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel available.
```

The Java6 JDK `java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel` and the Java7 JRE `java-1.7.0-openjdk` are both available, but the Java7 JDK does not appear.

Is there a non-default repository from which I can install this?  If so what is it?

- Distribution: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3 (Santiago)
- Kernel: 2.6.32-279.5.2.el6.x86_64

Comment: I removed the `-devel` suffix and it worked. See matched answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The package you are looking for is in the Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server Optional channel which may not be enabled.

Try this:

```
# yum repolist all
# yum-config-manager --enable rhel-6-server-optional-rpms
```

Comment: Is it possible to install without subscription?

Answer (score 2):

I removed the `-devel` and it worked:

```
yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk
```

If you already have another java version installed, don't forget to configure the system so that the new version will be used:

```
alternatives --config java
```

Comment: You installed a JRE and not a JDK.

Comment: @Routhinator - why do you think I "installed a JRE and not a JDK."?

Comment: Because the non -devel packages on RHEL systems are JRE only. The JDK rpms have -devel

Comment: So the `-devel` suffix means development hence `JDK` and not JRE? Thanks.

Comment: That is correct.